# Alternating sum of binomial coefficient times logarithm

Tags: summation, logarithms, binomial-coefficients

This question relates to a statistics [question on CrossValidated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357302/mathbbe-logx-max-x-min-of-weibullalpha-1) where the following summation appeared in an answer:

$$I(n) \equiv \ln n +  \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^k \ln k \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{for } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

Does anyone know of any simpler form for this expression?  (I doubt it, but thought I'd check with you brilliant people.)  Are there any useful bounds/approximations/asymptotic results for this expression?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211449/) might be helpful -- you can transform with $k=n-j$ and subtract $n\log n$, but then you have the case $n=m$ whereas the asymptotic analysis there assumes $n\gt m$. Still, you might be able to adapt the analysis.

Comment: By the way, I get that question suggested as one of the first when I enter your title in "Ask a question". You must have gotten the same display, no?

Answer (score 2):

The large-$n$ asymptotics of this sum are discussed in my paper [Asymptotics of Certain Sums Required in Loop Regularisation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04966). I found that the formula
$$ m\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y}(1-e^{-y})^{m-1}\log{y} \, dy = -\gamma - \sum_{k \geq 1} (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \log{k}  $$
was most useful: one can apply some standard asymptotic analysis (essentially an extension of Laplace's Method) to this integral to obtain the asymptotic expansion
$$ \sum_{k \geq 1} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} \log{k} \sim \log{\log{n}}-\gamma - \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r}\Gamma^{(r)}(1) (\log{n})^{-r}, $$
where $\Gamma^{(r)}$ is the $r$th derivative of the $\Gamma$-function.

---

It seems unlikely that a closed form exists. Closed forms in terms of polynomials in harmonic numbers do exist for sums of this sort with the logarithm replaced by negative integer powers of $k$, by extending some results of Euler (which is also done in my paper), but there's no way to extend the technique to other cases, at least as far as I know: the power being a negative integer is crucial in that case.