# Analytical proof for the convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Consider the following sequence

$\Xi_N=N\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} {N-1 \choose i} (-1)^{(i+1)} \log\left(i+1\right)$.

I numerically compute the asymptotic behavior of sequence and it turns out that the sequence approaches to a non-zero value as N goes to infinity. Now, I want to analytically prove that this sequence converges to a non-zero value as N goes to infinity.

Also, it can be proved that the sequence has another form as follows

$\Xi_N=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} {N \choose i} (-1)^{(i)} i \log\left(i\right)$.

Moreover, Using

$\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{m=1}^{i} \frac{1}{x+m} dx=\log(i+1)$

Then

$\Xi_N=N\sum_{m=1}^{N-1}{N-1 \choose m-1} (-1)^{m-1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x+m} dx $

Could you give me some advice?

Thanks

Comment: How can that be a series while $N<\infty$ ?

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Yes, you're right. Let say sequence.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the expression to work ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Yes, 100%, why?

Comment: That's kinda complex... So many products in one sum

Comment: You may pick $\sup\{\Xi_{N}\}$ for even values of $i$ and for odd ones.

Comment: That's a good one task though :D

Comment: Are you sure of your numerics? I tried some computations with Mathematica: the sequence seems to converge to somewhere close to $-0.3$ up to $n=45$, afterwards values become way more chaotic. This could be because we reach some sort of computational limit, but still for $n=50$ or $n=60$ the numbers do not seem wild enough to justify this. On the other hand such a sudden loss of regularity is also suspicious. Thus: are you sure of your numerics?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, yes, I observed that phenomena, and I considered that as the computational limit of "choose".  For instance, for N<42, my numerical computation via matlab shows that the sequence is about 0.2513.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano. This is why I asked the question in a comment. I stay very skeptical.

Comment: Is clear that the modulus of the sequence goes to infinity

Comment: The post [Proof ∑k=1n(nk)(−1)klogk=loglogn+γ+γlogn+O(1log2n)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64971/proof-sum-limits-k-1n-binomnk-1k-log-k-log-log-n-gamma-fr) might help you

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the reference provided by @Charly answers the question in the negative. I think it would be nice that one of you two, Charly and Mahdi, posts it as an answer, so that it can be marked as accepted and removed from the list of unanswered ones.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Not exactly, the technique used in the end of Part 1 can not be used in this question.

Comment: @Charly, Thanks for your reference.  I have added some lines to the question, but, unfortunately, the technique used in the end of Part 1 can not be longer used in this question.

Comment: If we set $${\Xi _N}(x) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{x^{i - 1}}\left( \begin{array}{l}
N\\
i
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}i\log i} $$ and $$\Delta (x) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{x^i}\left( \begin{array}{l}
N\\
i
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}\log i} $$

Comment: then $$\int {{\Xi _N}(x)}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\int {\left( {{x^{i - 1}}\left( \begin{array}{l}
N\\
i
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}i\log i} \right)dx} }  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{x^i}\left( \begin{array}{l}
N\\
i
\end{array} \right){{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}\log idx}  = \Delta (x)$$. I guess that we could use the technique used in the post to calculate $\Delta (x)$ and then derive. Note that we are looking for the an estimate of the value of ${\Xi _N}(1)$. As soon as I get home I'll give it a shoot!

Comment: @Charly: Hi, I have really got stuck into this problem. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Sorry, I have completely forgotten about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and the binomial theorem:

$$\Xi_{N+1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\left(e^{-x}-e^{-(k+1)x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-x})^N}{x e^{x}}\,dx$$

hence your limit is simply $\color{red}{\large 0}$ by the dominated convergence theorem, since
$$ f_N(x) = (1-e^{-x})^N $$
is bounded between $0$ and $1$ and behaves like $x^N$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Using Frullani's theorem is brilliant! How did you come up with this nice idea? btw THANKS.

Comment: @Mahdi: it is simply one of my favourites. To have an integral representation for logarithms is pretty useful, just like here :D

Comment: Hi Jack, I think you miss a term from $\Xi_{N+1}$. Based on the integral representation, we have
$\Xi_{N+1}=\color{red}{(N+1)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-x})^N}{x e^{x}}\,dx$.
In this case, what is the appropriate dominating function?

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer above seems to have missed one term, the correct form should be: $$\Xi _{N+1}=\left( N+1 \right) \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\left( 1-e^{-x} \right) ^N}{xe^x}dx}$$  Just as you say.
Notice that $$
for\,\,\forall n\geqslant 1, n\left( 1-e^{-x} \right) ^{n-1}\leqslant e^x\,\,, x\in \left[ 0,\infty \right)
$$
then we have:
$$ 
\forall N\geqslant 0, \frac{\left( N+1 \right) \left( 1-e^{-x} \right) ^N}{xe^x}\leqslant \frac{1}{x}\,\,,x\in \left( 0,\infty \right) $$
then you can use the dominated convergence theorem.